# How to fix the text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use this on my website ,but when I entered on Microsoft web expression is fine.When I see it on the web browser it makes this sketch all in the same line. I don't want it in the same ...I want this text to be as it seems and in my web broswer.I tried to use inline etc but it didn't work.Have any one how can I do that so it will be seemed exactly as it is on my web page ? Itry those two but anything displays it on my browser as it is

```
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""$o$o$o$o$o$oo$$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$""o$$$$$$$$$$"$"$$$$$$$o$"$$$$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$"$o$$$$""$oo $ ""      """$$$oo"$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$"o$$$$"   ""o  $oo o o       ""$$$o"$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$"o$$$"       oo$$$$$$$$$$o        "$$$o"$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$"o$$$  $  o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$oo       "$$$ $$$$</p>
<p>$$$"$$$"   "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$o$$$"        $$$o$$$</p>
<p>$$ $$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o o   o  "$$o"$</p>
<p>$"$$$"    o$$$$$$$$$"$$$$$$"" "$$$$$$"$$$$$  $$$"$</p>
<p>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$""""ooo"$$$$$$$$"   $$$"</p>
<p>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$            ""oo"$"$o""   $$$o</p>
<p>o$$$     o$$$$$$$$$$                """""$    o$$o</p>
<p>o$$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$o                   "o "oo$$o</p>
<p>o$$$  oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ooooooo$$$$$oo    $"$ "$$o</p>
<p>o$$$"  ""  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    " $$$</p>
<p>$ $$$       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    o$$"$</p>
<p>$$"$$o       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o   $$$o$</p>
<p>$$o$$$o       $$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o  $$$ $$</p>
<p>$$$o"$$o    "$""  "$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$oo$$$"$$$</p>
<p>$$$$o"$$$o        "     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$$"o$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$o"$$$o         oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$o"$$$$ooooo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"oo$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""oo$$$$$$$$$$$$ </p>


or this




<p class="auto-style10">$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""$o$o$o$o$o$oo$$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style10">$$$$$$$$$$$$""o$$$$$$$$$$"$"$$$$$$$o$"$$$$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style10">$$$$$$$$$"$o$$$$""$oo $ ""      """$$$oo"$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$$$$$"o$$$$"   ""o  $oo o o       ""$$$o"$$$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$$$"o$$$"       oo$$$$$$$$$$o        "$$$o"$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$$"o$$$  $  o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$oo       "$$$ $$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$"$$$"   "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$o$$$"        $$$o$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$ $$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o o   o  "$$o"$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$"$$$"    o$$$$$$$$$"$$$$$$"" "$$$$$$"$$$$$  $$$"$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$""""ooo"$$$$$$$$"   $$$"</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$            ""oo"$"$o""   $$$o</p>
<p class="auto-style3">o$$$     o$$$$$$$$$$                """""$    o$$o</p>
<p class="auto-style3">o$$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$o                   "o "oo$$o</p>
<p class="auto-style3">o$$$  oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ooooooo$$$$$oo    $"$ "$$o</p>
<p class="auto-style3">o$$$"  ""  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    " $$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$ $$$       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    o$$"$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$"$$o       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o   $$$o$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$o$$$o       $$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o  $$$ $$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$o"$$o    "$""  "$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$oo$$$"$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$$o"$$$o        "     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$$"o$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$$$$o"$$$o         oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style3">$$$$$$$$o"$$$$ooooo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style11">$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"oo$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p class="auto-style11">$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""oo$$$$$$$$$$$$ </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag

```html
<pre>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""$o$o$o$o$o$oo$$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$$$$""o$$$$$$$$$$"$"$$$$$$$o$"$$$$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$"$o$$$$""$oo $ ""      """$$$oo"$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$"o$$$$"   ""o  $oo o o       ""$$$o"$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$"o$$$"       oo$$$$$$$$$$o        "$$$o"$$$$$
<br/>$$$$"o$$$  $  o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$oo       "$$$ $$$$
<br/>$$$"$$$"   "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$o$$$"        $$$o$$$
<br/>$$ $$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o o   o  "$$o"$
<br/>$"$$$"    o$$$$$$$$$"$$$$$$"" "$$$$$$"$$$$$  $$$"$
<br/>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$""""ooo"$$$$$$$$"   $$$"
<br/>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$            ""oo"$"$o""   $$$o
<br/>o$$$     o$$$$$$$$$$                """""$    o$$o
<br/>o$$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$o                   "o "oo$$o
<br/>o$$$  oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ooooooo$$$$$oo    $"$ "$$o
<br/>o$$$"  ""  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    " $$$<
<br/>$ $$$       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    o$$"$
<br/>$$"$$o       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o   $$$o$
<br/>$$o$$$o       $$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o  $$$ $$
<br/>$$$o"$$o    "$""  "$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$oo$$$"$$$
<br/>$$$$o"$$$o        "     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$$"o$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$o"$$$o         oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$o"$$$$ooooo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"oo$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""oo$$$$$$$$$$$$ </p>
</pre>
```

Edit:
Used `<br/>` instead of multiple `<p>` tags to remove the padding inbetween the lines

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <title>
        Check This formatting Css
    </title>

</head>

<body>
  <pre>
```

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""$o$o$o$o$o$oo$$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

$$$$$$$$$$$$""o$$$$$$$$$$"$"$$$$$$$o$"$$$$$$$$$$$$

$$$$$$$$$"$o$$$$""$oo $ ""      """$$$oo"$$$$$$$$$

$$$$$$$"o$$$$"   ""o  $oo o o       ""$$$o"$$$$$$$

$$$$$"o$$$"       oo$$$$$$$$$$o        "$$$o"$$$$$

$$$$"o$$$  $  o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$oo       "$$$ $$$$

$$$"$$$"   "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$o$$$"        $$$o$$$

$$ $$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o o   o  "$$o"$

$"$$$"    o$$$$$$$$$"$$$$$$"" "$$$$$$"$$$$$  $$$"$

$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$""""ooo"$$$$$$$$"   $$$"

$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$            ""oo"$"$o""   $$$o

o$$$     o$$$$$$$$$$                """""$    o$$o

o$$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$o                   "o "oo$$o

o$$$  oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ooooooo$$$$$oo    $"$ "$$o

o$$$"  ""  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    " $$$$ $$$       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    o$$"$

$$"$$o       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o   $$$o$

$$o$$$o       $$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o  $$$ $$

$$$o"$$o    "$""  "$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$oo$$$"$$$

$$$$o"$$$o        "     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$$"o$$$$

$$$$$$o"$$$o         oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$

$$$$$$$$o"$$$$ooooo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$$$

$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"oo$$$$$$$$$

$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""oo$$$$$$$$$$$$

```
</html>
```

Comment: Ok please clear the requirement more or add screen shot of issue you are facing.

Comment: check your run code snippet its not the intended output

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""$o$o$o$o$o$oo$$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$""o$$$$$$$$$$"$"$$$$$$$o$"$$$$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$"$o$$$$""$oo $ ""      """$$$oo"$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$"o$$$$"   ""o  $oo o o       ""$$$o"$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$"o$$$"       oo$$$$$$$$$$o        "$$$o"$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$"o$$$  $  o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$oo       "$$$ $$$$</p>
<p>$$$"$$$"   "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$o$$$"        $$$o$$$</p>
<p>$$ $$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o o   o  "$$o"$</p>
<p>$"$$$"    o$$$$$$$$$"$$$$$$"" "$$$$$$"$$$$$  $$$"$</p>
<p>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$""""ooo"$$$$$$$$"   $$$"</p>
<p>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$            ""oo"$"$o""   $$$o</p>
<p>o$$$     o$$$$$$$$$$                """""$    o$$o</p>
<p>o$$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$o                   "o "oo$$o</p>
<p>o$$$  oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ooooooo$$$$$oo    $"$ "$$o</p>
<p>o$$$"  ""  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    " $$$</p>
<p>$ $$$       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    o$$"$</p>
<p>$$"$$o       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o   $$$o$</p>
<p>$$o$$$o       $$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o  $$$ $$</p>
<p>$$$o"$$o    "$""  "$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$oo$$$"$$$</p>
<p>$$$$o"$$$o        "     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$$"o$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$o"$$$o         oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$o"$$$$ooooo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"oo$$$$$$$$$</p>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""oo$$$$$$$$$$$$ </p>
```

if you don't want to use `pre` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the starting add a tag like this:

```
<pre>
<p>$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""$o$o$o$o$o$oo$$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$$$$""o$$$$$$$$$$"$"$$$$$$$o$"$$$$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$"$o$$$$""$oo $ ""      """$$$oo"$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$"o$$$$"   ""o  $oo o o       ""$$$o"$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$"o$$$"       oo$$$$$$$$$$o        "$$$o"$$$$$
<br/>$$$$"o$$$  $  o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"$$oo       "$$$ $$$$
<br/>$$$"$$$"   "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$o$$$"        $$$o$$$
<br/>$$ $$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o o   o  "$$o"$
<br/>$"$$$"    o$$$$$$$$$"$$$$$$"" "$$$$$$"$$$$$  $$$"$
<br/>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$""""ooo"$$$$$$$$"   $$$"
<br/>$o$$"    o$$$$$$$$$$            ""oo"$"$o""   $$$o
<br/>o$$$     o$$$$$$$$$$                """""$    o$$o
<br/>o$$$    o$$$$$$$$$$$$o                   "o "oo$$o
<br/>o$$$  oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ooooooo$$$$$oo    $"$ "$$o
<br/>o$$$"  ""  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    " $$$<
<br/>$ $$$       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o    o$$"$
<br/>$$"$$o       "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o   $$$o$
<br/>$$o$$$o       $$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o  $$$ $$
<br/>$$$o"$$o    "$""  "$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$oo$$$"$$$
<br/>$$$$o"$$$o        "     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$$"o$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$o"$$$o         oo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$o"$$$$ooooo$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"o$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$$o""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"oo$$$$$$$$$
<br/>$$$$$$$$$$$$$o$""$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$""oo$$$$$$$$$$$$ </p>
</pre>
```